# A field or property with the name 'bname' was not found on the selected data source

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, gridview, templatefield

I know this type of question has been asked multiple times, with solved answers. I've tried them all, but none of it seems to work. Please have a look and maybe help me in understanding where I am going wrong.

**.aspx**

```
      <asp:view ID="view2" runat="server">
            <asp:GridView ID="gvBatches" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CssClass="table-hover table" GridLines="None" Width="900px" ShowFooter="True" >
            <columns>
               <asp:BoundField  DataField="bname" HeaderText="Batch Name" />
            </columns>  
            </asp:GridView>
  </asp:view>
```

**.aspx.cs**

```
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
         {

            if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                if (ViewState["query"] == null)
                {
                    ViewState["query"] = "select course from tblCourses";
                }
                if (MultiView1.ActiveViewIndex == '1')
                {
                    bindgrid1();
                }

                bindgrid();
            }
        }

    protected void bindgrid1()
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBCS"].ConnectionString);
        DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
        using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(ViewState["query"].ToString(), con))
        {
            sda.Fill(dt1);
        }
        gvBatches.DataSource = dt1;
        gvBatches.DataBind();
    }
if (e.CommandName == "viewbat")
        {
            ViewState["query"] = "select bname from tblBatches where course='" + e.CommandArgument.ToString() + "'";
            MultiView1.ActiveViewIndex = 1;
        }
```

Multiview index is changed when a **LinkButton(commandName="viewbat")** is clicked on a different GridView(gvCourses with datafield="course" and that works fine).

The code throws same error even if the query is changed to simple:

```
select * from tblBatches
```

**Database design:**

[Database design is as shown, consists 'bname'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6q6Ky.png)

Comment: I don't see fully qualified naming in your code - are you sure you're querying the right database/schema?

Comment: And before you write any more code you need to read about, understand and start using parameterized queries. Your code is wide open to sql injection. My friend bobby tables loves this style of code. http://bobby-tables.com/

Comment: @Dave.Gugg I've attached the screenshot of the said table design. Yes! I am.To clarify, there are two gridviews, gvCourses and gvBatches, when a link button 'View Batches' is clicked, it switches to 'view 2 containing gvBatches which shows all the batches corresponding to that "course"(e.commandArgument.ToString()).
 gvCourse has datafield="course" from tblCourse, gvBatches has datafield="bname" from tblBatches.

Many linkbuttons such as add/delete/edit etc exist in gvCourses which work fine taking "course" as commandargument, but this, I have no idea.

Comment: @SeanLange Just started with programming sir, real amateur, I will use the resources you shared and look into what you said. Thank you!